# Load csv file on Google Drive in Python EC2 script

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am using EC2 for the first time, to run a machine learning task. I have set up my EC2 instance and my python script runs as intended. However, the script needs to read 3  large csv files during its run.

I have uploaded the csv files to Google Drive. I would like to be able to read the data via my ec2 script, something like this:

```
  dataframe = pd.read_csv('google_drive_file', index_col = 0)
```

Any help appreciated.

---

Update: I have found this suggestion, is this correct?

```
from StringIO import StringIO  # got moved to io in python3.

import requests
r = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ak1ecr7i0wotdGJmTURJRnZLYlV3M2daNTRubTdwTXc&output=csv')
data = r.content

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col = 0)
```

Comment: if you want to download the spreadsheet, in its entirety, as CSV, then use the Drive SDK. If you want to read specific cell ranges, use the Spreadshseet API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me. I ended up using S3. Make sure to set the permissions on your S3 buckets correctly. Then, simply:

```
conn = boto.connect_s3('access_key', 'secret_key')
bucket = conn.get_bucket('bucket_name')
df = pd.read_csv('file_address', index_col=0)
```